# Making a hover image a link

Tags: html, css

Not sure how to word the title, I am trying to make a image a link, the image has the hover "attribute" not sure how to word the question..
Below is my code:

HTML

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 100px;">
    <img src="pic\980_pcb.jpg" style="width:908.2px;height:398.05px position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;" />
    <span class="imgswap">  
    <a id="imgswap" href="#GPU"></a>  
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span.imgswap {
    background - image: url("pic/gpu_replace.jpg") no - repeat;
    height: 167 px;
    width: 163 px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 132.5 px;
    left: 286.5 px;
    background - repeat: no - repeat;
    display: block;
}

span.imgswap: hover {
    background: url("pic/gpu_replace.jpg") no - repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put your `span.imgswap` inside `<a>` tags (instead of vice-versa).  So the HTML should look like this:

```
<a id="imgswap" href="#GPU"><span class="imgswap"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just warp your  tag around the  tag and that image will become a link.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vENbRM

```
<a class="link" href="#">
  <img class="textimg" src="http://blackicemedia.com/presentations/2013-02-hires/img/awesome_tiger.svg" />  
</a>
```

---

```
img.textimg {
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
}

img.textimg:hover {
  background: black;
}
```